# How to update default react(CRA) to webpack4 and babel7?

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, create-react-app, webpack-4

If someone has done it, please help me with updating dependencies and webpack configuration file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will either need to eject and update configs yourself or wait for CRA v2 to be released which tackles both these issues.

More context here: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/3815

react-scripts is what abstracts and powers tooling like webpack and babel